# Refrigerator ice maker not working known/unknowns

Tags: refrigerator

Whirlpool refrigerator with ice maker and door dispenser. The refrigerator makes ice, but the dispenser is not working. I took the front assembly off and confirmed that the switch is good with a multimeter.

This leaves me with:

- The motor is bad
- or the circuit board is bad

Is there any other mechanism that could be involved that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything else it you could check. But, if it's a slide-out unit you can jiggle, push, pull & twist it to see if it just came a little loose & has a bad connection. Ice overflows or overfills can jockey them around to inoperability.

Also, check the manual of course. If you can uninstall & reinstall, you may find unplugging (turning off the circuit breaker, if known) the fridge for this operation & then plugging it back it clears any fault & gets it working again. In that case it may be a temporary fault or a first fault in the motor going bad & drawing too much power or not working at all. If the "reset" works, then you'll have to wait for it to fail again & it may not.